# Need to go from 30 amp to 60amp breaker

Tags: electrical, wiring, rewire

I'm trying to get more amperage to my pool panel outside to install a heat pump. I have the right breaker to install and the 6 gauge wire to pull through. My question is do I just have to do the hot wires (red and black) or do I also have to pull a new  6 gauge neutral and ground wire? (white and green)Currently everything is 10 gauge wire.

Comment: Can you provide the nameplate information or spec sheet for the heat pump you're putting in?  Also, what size and type is the existing conduit, and can you post photos of the labeling on the pool panel itself?

Comment: You only need black for the hot conductor. What are your loads? And the heat pump rating many of the heat pumps I have installed require 120-/240. Do you have a sub panel out there?

Comment: The heat pump is 208-230 volt.  Conduit is 3/4 all smooth radius bends. Shouldnt have any problems pulling new wire.  I have installed pool heaters before but the sub panel outside always had enough amperage. I'm just looking for the proper way to up my pool panel amperage up from 30 amps to 60.